Unable to Boot Windows from NVMe SSD After Removing Old SSD
I  previously had Windows installed on an SSD. Recently, I upgraded my PC by installing a new NVMe SSD and also installed Windows on it. However, upon booting my PC, the Windows Boot Manager presents me with a choice between the old Windows installation on the SSD and the new installation on the NVMe SSD. The issue arises when I disconnect the old SSD and attempt to boot the PC - instead of loading Windows from the NVMe SSD, it directs me to the boot menu. In the boot priorities listed in the BIOS/UEFI settings, only the Windows Boot Manager is visible, with no option to directly select the NVMe SSD.
I've checked the BIOS/UEFI settings, and the NVMe SSD is recognized. However, in the boot menu order, only the Windows Boot Manager is listed, and there is no option to select the NVMe SSD directly.
Additionally, I'm considering formatting the old SSD since I no longer need it. However, I'm concerned that doing so might affect the boot process for the NVMe SSD. Reinstalling Windows on the NVMe SSD is not an option as it already contains crucial data.

You need create new boot partition (ESP) on new one. It's easy for professionals, but difficult for beginners. You can use something like EASY UEFI, DiskGenius.

@Mr.Key7 First option look realiable, any innstructions/article/video?

perhaps i will give instructions as answer

This sounds like the Windows installer found the existing boot manager on the old SSD and reused that instead of installing a new one.
Since it sounds like a clean install anyway, easiest would be just to reformat and install Windows without the old drive present.
You may also try to use the Windows installer to repair the installation while the old drive is not present.
Also you might want to consider just mirroring your old drive, if there's enough space. You'll have to make a few registry adjustments for it to boot (currently in mobile, but you should be able to look up details).

I want a solution that doesn't involve formatting the nvme or reinstalling Windows on the NVMe since it already contains important data.

Easy way for beginner, backup important data first, then reinstall OS in the new NVMe without the old inserted.

If don't like reInstall, alternative use this way.
This guide need basic software knowledges. Do it as your own risk.
Backup important data in case something unexpected happens.
Generally, the steps are: create an ESP partition and make Windows boot manager in new disk.
- Create ESP Partition
Check the new NVMe Disk, if there are not available free spaces, you need make the free with shrink command.
to check from cmd as admin echo list volume | diskpart
to shrink volume: (echo sel vol 7& echo shrink minimum=150) | diskpart
replace vol 7 according the volume want to shrinked from the new disk.
150 = 150MB. your choice for it.
To create new ESP, save it as .bat file e.g. newesp.bat, and execute as admin.
replace disk 0 according to the new nvme disk.
To check it from CMD as admin echo list disk | diskpart
@Echo Off
(
echo select disk 0
echo create partition msr size=16
echo create partition efi size=100
echo format quick fs=fat32 label="System"
echo exit
) | Diskpart

- Make New Boot Manager
Download EASYUEFI from hasleo. Alternative karanpc
After installed, open it and select manage EFI System partition > Rebuild EFI System partition.

Destination Disk = the new disk
Boot partition   = new Windows partition in NVMe
ESP              = new ESP partition in NVMe.
